# Subscription level Role similar to Reader but preventing Key Vault secret access & storage key access

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-security, azure-rbac

I am looking for some RBAC role at subscription level, something like 'Reader' but unlike Reader, it should not allow accessing Key Vault secrets and Azure Storage blob keys. Is there any such role at subscription level?

Comment: Key Vault secrets should not be viewable with Azure RBAC roles. Key Vault has its own access policies that are required to be set to access secrets.

Comment: @juunas thanks. Do you mean if we provide Reader access to an individual for our subscription, he won't be able to go to key vault resource through the Azure portal and view the list of secrets? I am not talking about app level access here. And also what about viewing keys for Azure Storage resources?

Comment: No, they would not see secrets. Instead, there is an error complaining about access. Keys I'm not sure. How about you create a test user in your AAD, add them a Reader role on a sub/resource group and test it? ;)

Comment: @juunas do you mean creation of a 'guest user'? a normal 'New User' option  appears disabled for me. I guess from RBAC perspective it should not matter even if I create a guest user I suppose. I will try it out. thanks

Comment: keys should not be viewable by reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something like 'Reader' but unlike Reader, it should not allow accessing Key Vault secrets and Azure Storage blob keys.

In your case, the `Reader` role is suitable.

To access the azure keyvault secret/key/certificate, the user needs to assigned corresponding permissions like `get, list, set, delete` in `Access policies`. Without the permissions, he will not be able to access them. But you should note, don't assign the user as the `Owner/Contributor/Key Vault Contributor` roles(maybe there are other roles, just a tip), because the user with these roles can add himself to the `Access policies`.
More details about keyvault access control, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault).

To access the Azure Storage blob keys, the user will need `Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action` permission which the `Reader` does not have, so it is also suitable.

---

Have a test for you with the `Reader` role:

Storage:

[image]

Keyvault:

[image]

[image]

[image]